# Importar gran archivo csv con laravel excel

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-excel

tengo un archivo csv "uso_suelo.csv" con 130.000 filas aprox y mas de 40 columnas

Estoy trabajando con `laravel 5.8` y `postgresql` y tratando de importarlo con `laravel excel 3.1`, usando las funciones que proporciona:

Este es mi clase Import en la que solo importo 18 columnas que necesito (colocaré solo 3 para no alargar tanto el código):

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\UsoSuelo;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class UsoSueloImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow, WithChunkReading, ShouldQueue
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new UsoSuelo([
            'cod_pais'     => $row['cod_pais'],
            'cod_fundo'     => $row['cod_fundo'],
            'nom_fundo'     => $row['nom_fundo'],

        ]);
    }

    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
        return 5000;
    }
}
```

Aqui mi controlador que es básicamente un llamado a otra función:

```
class ImportController extends Controller
{
    use storeTrait  {
        storeUsoSuelo as storeUsoSuelos;
        storeFundo as storeFundos;
        storeFundoGrilla as storeFundoGrillas;
        storeCuadrante as storeCuadrantes;

    }

        public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $usoSuelo = 'uso_suelo.csv';
            $this->storeUsoSuelos($usoSuelo);

            $cuadrante = 'cuadrantes.csv';
            $this->storeCuadrantes($cuadrante);

            $fundo = 'mv_qav_fundos.csv';
            $this->storeFundos($fundo);

            $fundoGrilla = 'fundos_grilla.csv';
            $this->storeFundoGrillas($fundoGrilla);

            return Redirect::route('filtro-datos.index');
    }}
```

Y por último mi archivo storeTrait.php donde hago el llamado a mi clase Import

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Imports\UsoSueloImport;
use App\Imports\CuadrantesImport;
use App\Imports\FundosImport;
use App\Imports\FundosGrillasImport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

trait storeTrait{

    public function storeUsoSuelo($archivo) {
        Excel::import(new UsoSueloImport,$archivo); 
    }
    public function storeFundo($archivo) {
        Excel::import(new FundosImport,$archivo); 
    }
    public function storeFundoGrilla($archivo) {
        Excel::import(new FundosGrillasImport,$archivo); 
    }
    public function storeCuadrante($archivo) {
        Excel::import(new CuadrantesImport,$archivo); 
    }
}
```

Porqué hago esto? Ya que necesito subir varios archivos a la vez, cabe mencionar que con un archivo pequeño de "uso_suelo.csv" de menos de 1000 filas esto funciona perfectamente

Pero cuando trato de cargar el de 130.000 filas tras 1 minuto me sale el siguiente error:

```
"Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded"
```

Dado esto cambie mi `php.ini` y le puse esto `max_execution_time=240`

Pero me sigue dando el mismo error, y luego del minuto solo se han importado 5000 filas

Porfa alguien que me ayude :(

Answer (score 0):

Para manejar la importación de numerosa cantidad de filas, es bueno acompañar el `Chunk` import con `Batch`.

> With the WithBatchInserts concern you can limit the amount of queries
> done by specifying a batch size.
> This will drastically reduce the import duration.

Por lo que el primer paso sería hacer pruebas para obtener el número óptimo que debes usar aquí.

```
public function batchSize(): int
{
    return 1000;
}
```

Posterior a eso, debes recordar que `max_execution_time` está en segundos, por lo que 240 pueden no ser suficientes. Una manera de evitar dicha limitación es utilizando:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Ya que haciendo eso no hay límite pero OJO, **no es recomendable hacer eso**. Y en general, no es recomendable actualizar la variable `max_execution_time` en absoluto.

Lo que se debe hacer en lugar de eso es optimizar el proceso. En tu caso, utilizando Batch Imports y también hacer uso de [Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues) o colas, en Laravel.

Hay un ejemplo en la documentación de [Laravel Excel](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/queued.html) que puedes usar para guiarte. Implementar el proceso con colas, ayudará a que tu aplicación ejecute esta tarea, que toma mucho tiempo, en segundo plano.